# MOTOROLA RF7000 Series Switch between image

Tags: wireless

For clustered environments both Controllers must operate on the same firmware version. Now my situation on backup controller is [image: show boot output]

how can I force using version 5.5 on next boot?

Comment: I cannot understand why people cannot bother to download and READ the freely available manual.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
boot system [primary|secondary] {on <DEVICE-NAME>}
```

[WiNG CLI Reference Manual](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Wireless+Networks/Wireless+LAN/Unified+Access+Platforms/RFS7000_US-EN) (any reference manual)